# How to get Skype usernames from a file using grep?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I want to export a Skype ID from a webpage, and the data is like this:

```
contact skype:youarefriend"
```

I just want to export `youarefriend` in my result. I could use:

```
grep -oP 'skype:.*?"'
```

But the result is `skype:youarefriend"`. Can I get the output without the `skype:` prefix?

Comment: `.*?` is not a meaningful expression, being equivalent to an empty expression. You meant something like `.*?"`.

Comment: @ooga: it (`.*?`) is a non-greedy regex.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print $1 if m/skype:(\w+)/;' file`

Comment: @ooga: Either half asleep or simply unaware of non-greedy matching.  See [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) under 'Regular Expressions' and in particular the Quantifiers subsection.

Comment: @ooga :i want to stop at first appear of "

Comment: Sorry. I apparently misread your grep line. I didn't notice the double-quote at the end. I was just saying that `.*?` without something else after it is not a useful expression since it would always match zero characters (the minimum in that case). But it's okay if you have the double-quote after it (or something to match and make the expression useful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [escape sequence `\K`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k). What this nifty sequence does is resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence:

```
grep -oP "skype:\K\w+" file
```

Or a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion. This looks behind to see if there's a `skype:`, and if so, matches the word (`\w+`):

```
grep -oP "(?<=skype:)\w+" file
```

If you want to capture everything up until `"`, you could use the following regex. Similar to the previous regex, this looks behind to see if there's a `skype:`, and if so, matches one more more characters that is not a `"` (essentially everything until the first occurrence of `"`):

```
grep -oP '(?<=skype:)[^"]+' file
```

If you'd like to be more specific, and match only [valid Skype usernames](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA94/what-is-a-skype-name) (must start with a letter, can contain only letters, numbers, and the punctuations `.`, `.`, `_` and `-`), you can use this:

```
grep -ioP "(?<=skype:)[a-z][\w.,-]{6,32}" file
```

(In case you've been wondering why there isn't a `_` in the regex, it is because `\w` includes the `_` too; it is a shorthand representation for the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. The `-i` option is used in the grep command to **i**gnore  case  distinctions in  both  the    regex and the input file.)

Comment: Very nice! I never knew this was possible with `grep`. I normally reach for `sed` to do things like this

Comment: i am not very clear for your "grep -oP "skype:\K(\w+)" file" ,can you explain a bit about :(\w+)

Comment: `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included. (e.g. throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.)

Comment: @YOU: `\w+` is a sequence of one or more 'word' characters, meaning alphanumerics or underscore.

Comment: your answer was great,but how can i still get some special character like "?" ,and stop at a specify character.

Comment: If you want to allow other characters, use a character class. `grep -oP "skype:\K[\w?]+" file`

Comment: @YOU: Updated the answer with some explanation. I've also added an alternative solution that performs a slightly more stricter matching.

Answer (score 5):

If you've got Perl regexes (as you have if you're using `-P`), then use a lookbehind to exclude the `skype:` and a lookahead to exclude the `"`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=skype:).*?(?=")'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'help "skype:someone" else "hi there"' | grep -oP '(?<=skype:).*?(?=")'
someone
$
```

Comment: it still get " in the result :  youarefriend"

Answer (score 1):

Yet another form:

```
grep -oP '(?<=skype:)[^"]+' file
```

Comment: @YOU `(?<=skype:)` is a look-behind assertion like everyone is telling. `[^"]+` matches any character that's not (`^`) `"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also be precise and find out exactly what characters are possible in the regex you want to match.  i.e. [Skype usernames](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA94/what-is-a-skype-name) can have only letters, numbers, periods, commas, dashes or underscores.

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=skype:)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z|0-9|,|\-|_|\.]+" <<<"contact skype:s0me,we-ird_n.ame\""
s0me,we-ird_n.ame
```

Note this would not match anything starting with a non-letter as is the Skype requirement.